# Issues with AWS Textract API with StartExpenseAnalysis

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I have a process in AWS. It starts with a file upload in S3 which triggers a Lambda function which passes the uploaded file into Textract to be analyzed. I am dealing with invoices andd credit memos so this pertains to the StartExpenseAnalysis API.

Here is my Lambda function that send the S3 file into Textract for analysis:

```
from logging import exception
import boto3
import time
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

sns_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-..."
role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::..."
textract = boto3.client('textract', region_name='us-east-1')



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print("event collected is {}".format(event))
    for record in event['Records'] :
        s3_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        print("Bucket name is {}".format(s3_bucket))
        s3_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        print("Bucket key name is {}".format(s3_key))
        from_path = "s3://{}/{}".format(s3_bucket, s3_key)
        print("from path {}".format(from_path))
        textract_result = process_document(s3_bucket, s3_key)

        if textract_result :
            print("job id returned..") 
            metadata_results = add_jobid_to_metadata(s3_bucket, s3_key, textract_result)
            if metadata_results :
                print("Metadata added successfully completed")
                return textract_result
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
        

def add_jobid_to_metadata(s3_bucket, s3_key, JobId):
    try:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        metadata = {'JobId': JobId}


        put_object_response = s3_client.put_object(
                                Bucket=s3_bucket,
                                Key=s3_key,    
                                Metadata=metadata
                            )

        if put_object_response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            print("Successfully added metadata..")
            return True
        else:
            print("Metadata failed..")
            return False
    except Exception as exception :
        print("Exception happened message is: ", exception)
        return False
    

def process_document(s3_bucket, s3_key):
    sleepy_time = 1
    retry = 0
    flag = 'False'
    try:
        while retry < 4 and  flag == 'False' :
            response = textract.start_expense_analysis(
                DocumentLocation={
                                'S3Object': {
                                    'Bucket': s3_bucket,
                                    'Name': s3_key
                                    }
                                },
                                    NotificationChannel=
                                    {
                                    'RoleArn': role_arn,
                                    'SNSTopicArn': sns_arn
                                    }
                            )
            
            print(response)
            if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
                print('Start Job Id: ' + response['JobId'])
                print("Job has been sent to Textract for analysis")
                flag == 'True'
                return response['JobId']
            else:
                time_to_sleep = 2**retry
                retry +=1
                time.sleep(time_to_sleep)

    except Exception as exception :
        print("Exception happened message is: ", exception)
        return False
```

Everything works great except the part where I send it to Textract.

I am getting the error: **An error occurred (BadDocumentException) when calling the StartExpenseAnalysis operation: The document is empty**

When I am uploading a document, it is immediately going to 0 B. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.